# How do you perform an animation on a grid length with GridUnitType.Star?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the following class to perform animations on some grid row heights:

```
internal class GridLengthAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{
    static GridLengthAnimation()
    {
        FromProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(GridLength),
            typeof(GridLengthAnimation));

        ToProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof(GridLength), 
            typeof(GridLengthAnimation));
    }

    public override Type TargetPropertyType 
    {
        get 
        {
            return typeof(GridLength);
        }
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new GridLengthAnimation();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty;
    public GridLength From
    {
        get
        {
            return (GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty;
    public GridLength To
    {
        get
        {
            return (GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue, 
        object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        double fromVal = ((GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty)).Value;
        double toVal = ((GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty)).Value;

        if (fromVal > toVal)
        {
            return new GridLength((1 - animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value) * (fromVal - toVal) + toVal, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        }
        else
            return new GridLength(animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value * (toVal - fromVal) + fromVal, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    }
}
```

However, this does not work when attempting to animate a row height to anything with `GridUnitType.Star`, as it results in choppy animation due to the many recalculations necessary with rapidly changing a proportional unit.

One possible solution would be to determine the resulting height of a row in pixels (if you were to use some GridUnitType.Star) and then simply start the animation using that value, and after the animation is complete set it to the corresponding GridUnitType.Star. However I'm not sure how you would go about determining the resulting height of a row in pixels.

Let's say you set your row to 1*, and let the window render. You could then call ActualHeight on the row and determine what 1* is in pixels for the current window state, which could be used in the animation. But is there any way to calculate this without having to actually set the row to 1* (for obvious visual reasons)?

Alternatively, is there a better way to perform a grid length animation that supports `GridUnitType.Star`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two alternative approaches I use for this sort of thing.

Both rely on putting my content to animate inside another container. It's the height of this I animate and the parent row height remains constant.

One approach relies on a rectangle or some such in a row which I use to obtain the full "*" height of that row.
I then animate height from 0 to that rectangle's actualheight on my container.

The other approach.
Animates scaleX and scaleY in a scaletransform on the child container from 0 to 1.

Comment: I actually figured out to do this on my own using the first approach. Just created a container inside the row to hold the views and got the size of that in pixels (even if the row size is 0 the container still has a height, even if it is invisible). After the animation using purely pixels I just set it to star to handle resizing afterwards.